# How to access local web server from another computer

Tags: linux, networking, webserver, port, jekyll

I know this may be asked in different threads, but I really couldn't find a solutions for my simple problem.

I have a web server (Ubuntu) on port 4000 running and I want to access it from my second computer (same network). I don't mind if it's exposed to the Internet (it's only temporally).

I can ping the web server computer, but port 4000 is not reachable.
Can some give me a simple solution for this problem? That would make my day.

#### EDIT:

I run `jekyll serve`

#### EDIT:

Okay I found a really helpful blog entry for solving my problem.
[link](https://zarino.co.uk/post/jekyll-local-network/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think this is not the way to go. I assume you have git. Just clone the repo and type 'jekyll serve'. Easy.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running Apache2 webserver edit your configuration like this:

From:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:4000
```

To:

```
Listen 4000
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/bind.html for reference.

Configuration examples for nginx are available here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

Restart/reload your apache2 or nginx service to apply configuration changes.

Your webserver is now reachable through http://[webserverip]:4000